# SQL WORKBENCH: REFERENCES in foreign key command error "REFERENCES" is not valid in this position, expecting( '('

Tags: mysql-workbench

My REFERENCES keeps getting this error in MySQL Workbench. Here is the code

Use my_database;

```
Create table bands (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
primary key (id)
);
```

```
Create Table albums(
 id int Not NUll auto_increment,
 name Varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 release_year INT,
 band_id INT NOT NULL,
 primary key (id),
 foreign key band_id references bands(id)
 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You forget to put `(` and `)` bracket between foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE albums(
 id int Not NUll AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name Varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 release_year INT,
 band_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id),
 FOREIGN KEY (band_id) REFERENCES bands(id)
 );
```